# python ZipImportError: bad local file header only when import in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, ipython, setuptools, jupyter, importerror

I have a custom internal package (Python 2.7) I created and was trying to demo it in a `jupyter notebook`, but it's not importing. I get:

```
ZipImportError: bad local file header: path/to/package.egg
```

There are so few results on Google for the `ZipImportError: bad local file header` that I thought I copied it wrong. The package imports fine in cmd, eclipse, spyder just fine. No idea what the issue is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a fix - just upgrade `setuptools`. I upgraded via `pip`. My `setuptools` version that I used to install the package via `python setup.py install` was 23.0.0 and is now 34.1.0. After that, I just re-installed the package and it imported without error in the `jupyter notebook`.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing setuptools v50+, it can help you

```
pip install setuptools==51.2.0
```